# How to join an Active Directory with a Linux machine

Tags: linux, centos, windows-server-2003, active-directory, ldap

How can I join an Active Directory domain with a Linux machine?

Will it work with Ubuntu, Redhat, CentOS? Are there any with which it will not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it works. check this [Can Linux Desktops Live in an Active Directory World?](http://reverendted.wordpress.com/2006/09/12/linux-goes-mad/)

There few ways to connect with active directory..

using `winbind` or `samba server integration` or `Likewise Open 6.0`

check these links to know how to connect with active directory.

http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/linux-with-active-directory/

[Active Directory Integration with Samba for RHEL/CentOS 5](http://www.linuxmail.info/active-directory-integration-samba-centos-5/)

[Join RedHat Linux to Microsoft Active Directory LinkWise](http://thomasvogt.wordpress.com/2010/07/28/join-redhat-linux-to-microsoft-active-directory/)

http://www.admin-hints.com/2009/04/join-linux-redhat-based-machine-to.html

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-join-a-windows-2003-active-directory-domain-from-linux-system.html

http://schoolitexpert.com/Operating-Systems/Linux/join-linux-to-an-active-directory-domain.html

Answer (score 1):

[Centrify](http://www.centrify.com/blogs/tomkemp/join_ubuntu_to_active_directory_domain.asp) works well. We are running Kubuntu 10.10 connecting to a Windows Server 2003 Active Directory.

Comment: Hah, beat me to it!

Answer (score 0):

[SADMS](http://sadms.objectif-libre.com/) claims to offer this functionality in an easy to use way.  I haven't got around to trying it yet, but I will soon, I hope.